# Query execution from C# stops in DB and does not fill the data table

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a code in `C#` like below to extract data from DB

```
foreach (var query in _queries)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string _strQuerytoExecute = query;

    if (_strQuerytoExecute.Contains("{FromDate}") && _strQuerytoExecute.Contains("{ToDate}"))
    {
          _strQuerytoExecute= _strQuerytoExecute.Replace("{FromDate}", _strFromDate).Replace("{ToDate}", _strToDate);

    }

   orcmd.CommandText = _strQuerytoExecute;
   orcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

   orcmd.Connection = orccon;

   if (orccon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
   {
       orccon.Open();
   }

   OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(orcmd);

   oda.Fill(dt);

   qrds.Tables.Add(dt);
}
```

To extract data from a query that runs for about 1 min 20 secs, the query execution stops in DB after 40 secs when executed from **C# code** and it shows still executing in code after `qrds.Tables.Add(dt);`,  but when I run manually in DB tool the query executes

In the Active Query list in DB the query execution stops after 40 secs without giving any result

```
select g.sid,s.sql_text,s.sql_fulltext,g.username,osuser, to_char(sql_exec_start,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') as querystarttime
from v$session g 
INNER JOIN v$sql s ON s.sql_id=g.sql_id
WHERE status = 'ACTIVE';
```

The query I am talking about has no parameters so it will not go inside the `Replace` part of the code

Do please anybody point me I have to add any special code do I have to add?

**Edit:** I have optimized the query and now it runs for about 43 secs only but still the execution of the query from application stops

Comment: Please share a [mcve] (in particular, what is the final value of `_strQuerytoExecute`).

Comment: At the very least this looks like a SQL injection problem.

Comment: 1 minute 20 is a *long* time to be talking to a database, and you'll probably need to tweak the timeout values on the command - i.e. `orcmd.CommandTimeout`; however, as @mjwills notes: I'd be more concerned about the `Replace` - that should *absolutely* be a parameter (another part of me is screaming "noooooo don't use data-tables", but ... that's more subjective; parameters are not subjective)

Comment: Hi Marc Gravell I had tried the `orcmd.CommandTimeout` also but still after few secs the query execution stops in DB

Comment: For the query which I am talking about does not have any parameters so it will go into the `Replace` section

Comment: `For the query which I am talking about does not have any parameters so it will go into the Replace section` ← That is the problem. If you are using `replace` for something like filtering you should be using parameters. Example: `where startDate > :fromDate` and then add a `OracleParameter` to the command of the correct DbType and value.

Comment: Igor Sorry for the typo it will not go into the `replace` section

Comment: After that string-replace, does `_strQuerytoExecute` still contain a valid command? Try and execute that directly (outside the C# app). If it became invalid because of the Replace, *that* is one of the reasons why you should switch to parameters as previously mentioned.

Comment: Hi Hans Kesting, Yes `_strQuerytoExecute` is a valid command and it executes in a DB tool and produces results but from C# application no result is got.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that disposing the OracleConnection inside or outside of the loop should fix the problem

```
using (OracleConnection orconn = new OracleConnection(oracleConnectionString))
{
           ...
            OracleCommand orcmd = new OracleCommand(query, orconn);
           
            orconn.Open();
            
            OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(orcmd);

            oda.Fill(dt);
            ...
}
```